# Php can't reach file on external drive

Tags: php

I have php script which can tell does file exist or not.

```
<?php
$file_path = "/media/user/external drive/folder/file.txt";
if (file_exists($file_path))
{
echo "file exists";
}
else
{
echo "file does not exist";
}
?>
```

If i try reach file on external drive i'll get "else" statement. but if i'll try get file not from external drive ex: /home/user/desktop/file.txt or /var/log/file.txt it will sucessfuly find the file. Why? How i can reach this file on external drive?
UPD: tried with scandir() and it can see the /media/user but it can't see the external drive at all

Comment: Do you get any warnings? Could be a permissions issue. Make sure PHP is set to report errors and warnings.

Comment: @ADyson nothing. It's not a permission issue for sure. I gave all of them

Comment: Well it's either that, or the path is wrong, pretty much. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php lists a couple of other less common reasons it can fail, too.

Comment: @Classic_Fungus Please [edit] your question to include the result of `var_dump($s, file_exists($s), is_dir($s), is_readable($s));` where `$s` is every part of your path like `$s='/media/';`, `$s='/media/user/';`, `$s='/media/user/external drive/';`, etc.. That way you can see the permissions of each directory and how PHP will see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update permissions using following command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /media/user -R
```

and now apache sees external drive